# angular2 metadata for environment variables

Tags: angular, configuration, metadata

Will try to describe my problem as much as possible

I have 2 environment files, one for dev and one for prod, for dev is easy because is local but for prod we have 3 servers and when we build the app it generates an app.js that basically pass the enviroment variables that are basically strings:

Basically it contains this:

const ProdConfig: EnvConfig = 
    {
      ENV: 'PROD',
      API: 'http://[ip address]:82/api',
      TOKEN: 'http://[ip address]:82/token',
      SLIPS_API: 'http://[ip address]:83/api',
    };

in the [ip address] it contains the ip address of the server, the problem is that it works for one server so when we move the app to other the other server we need to manually edit the app.js and correct the ip address.

Is there a way to make the ip address configurable by an external config file in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

The IP address for your API server shouldn't change. Your 3 web servers' IP address should have no impact on the address of the box that runs your API code.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: How does it not?